# Is it possible to create a shortcut that opens a data viewer for the dataframe under cursor with vscode-jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-extensions

New vscode user here.
Just discovered the python interactive mode in the vscode-jupyter extension and it seems quite powerful.

I was wondering if it is possible to implement a shortcut that will open the data viewer window associated with the dataframe under the cursor?

Here is a quick sketch of what the workflow can look like

1. Move the cursor to `df`
   [image]
2. Execute the line if `df` is not yet defined
   [image]
3. Move the cursor to the interactive python group so as to see `df` in the jupyter: variables tab
   [image]
4. Open the data viewer window associated with `df`
   [image]

I am willing to take a shot at implementing this shortcut, but as stated above, I am quite a newbie in vscode. Before getting started I would therefore love to hear from you **if it is difficult to implement this shortcut (or even simply feasible)? Are the required functions exposed by the vscode-jupyter API?**

Any other pointers that can help me are of course very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems impossible for now, and it's illogic, as you need to select the variable which you want to expose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry if this is a naive question, but I am not sure to understand why this is illogic. When clicking on the icon next to `df` to open the data viewer (screenshot 3 of the OP), this actually implies that the desired variable is passed across groups. But maybe I am missing something here.  I am really new to vscode

Comment: @greg hor I have tried to set the shortcut, but it does not work. I think that's reasonable, as one data view page only displays one variable, when you have several variables, the shortcut can not know which one you want to display.

Comment: thank you for giving this a try. What you explained above makes sense. 
I will accept your answer for now. And if we find a solution in the future, we can still reopen the post

Comment: Rstudio has a similar feature where you can go View(data_frame) to bring up the interactive viewer for that particular variable. Not illigical and definatly something that vscode is missing

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to jupyter extension on vscode community

Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts and
type this in the search bar:

*"jupyter.showDataViewer"*

now click on the result and customize your own shortcut for it

[image guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2O3B.png)

Comment: Thanks, I ll take a look!